# Easiest way to set keybindings for strings

Tags: key-bindings

I use strings like "include/lib-one", "include/lib-two", "src/lib-three" all the time.

Is there an easy way to set shortcuts for these strings, e.g. as `C-c 1`, `C-c 2` and so on?

Comment: There's `abbrev` or `yasnippet`. But auto-completion for your specific language would be better.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can also use `define-key` or `global-set-key` like this:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c a") "include/lib-one")
```

I've used `C-c a` instead of `C-c 1` because the former is a reserved-for-end-users sequence, whereas the latter is reserved for major modes. See <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd>`(elisp) Key Binding Conventions` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Comment: Also of note: this method executes the keyboard macro defined by the given string. So you can have things like `"\C-j"` in there, and it would be as if you hit `C-j`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `insert` function to insert strings at point. You can define keybinding to an invocation of this function. For example,

```
(define-key your-mode-map (kbd "C-c 1") (lambda () (insert "include/lib-one")))
```

Comment: thanks! One more question: what is your-mode-map?

Comment: It is the name of the mode where you want this keybinding. For example, if you want this in `c++-mode` only, you will replace `your-mode-map` by `c++-mode-map`. Alternatively, if you want it to be defined globally, use `global-set-key`.

Comment: I've tried adding similar keybindings to my .emacs file, but they are never taken into account when I launch emacs.  Is there something that I'm missing?